# Twitter Oauth javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth

I am trying to use andreassolberg's JSO OAuth library for implementing twitter signin via OAuth.My config is as follows

```
var config = {
  providerID: "twitter",
  client_id: "****",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost/jso/test/index.html",
  authorization: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
  scopes: { request: ["https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"]},
  debug:true
};
```

The twitter response is like this,

> "There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we
>   need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go
>   back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it
>   was probably just a mistake."

Comment: Verify that your system clock is set correctly